# Inline variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In one of my requirement, I like to create command at start of script and like to fill those variable later. For example:

```
# Global
Mylistdir="ls -la $MYDAIR"

#now after some code  I want to create this variable
MYDAIR="/data/dir/"
#Now like to run taht command on /data/dir
echo "$Mylistdir"
```

How can I do it?

I tried it as

```
Mylistdir="ls -la `$MYDAIR`"`
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Think - but not sure `alias`

Comment: no. I will use this in a script file

Comment: At best this question is confusing.

Comment: This is a subset of BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Using it in a script making shortcuts is only confusing. Just write the complete commands.

Comment: BTW, pay attention to your quoting. Using double-quotes with backticks inside makes `$MYDAIR` be run as a command *when Mylistdir is defined*, and the output be stored. (Since you can't run a directory name as a command, an error at this time is entirely to be expected).

Comment: ...if you want to defer evaluation, you need to put single-quotes on the outside at definition time -- and don't use backticks unless you know *exactly* what you're doing!

Answer (score 2):

Code should be stored in functions, not variables. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a full description of rationale, and the bugs caused by ignoring this rule.

```
Mylistdir() { ls -la "$MYDAIR"; }
MYDAIR=/data/dir
Mylistdir
```

If you **absolutely must** store code in a variable, use `eval`:

```
Mylistdir='ls -la "$MYDAIR"'
MYDAIR=/data/dir
eval "$Mylistdir"
```

...but mind the caveats given in [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

---

The original code proposed in the question was written as follows:

```
Mylistdir="ls -la `$MYDAIR`"`
```

...now, that's broken for several reasons:

- It uses double-quotes on the outside, causing any expansions to be performed immediately at assignment time instead of at a later evaluation time.
- It puts backticks around `$MYDAIR`, causing the value of that variable *as it exists at assignment time* to be string-split, glob-expanded, and then run as a command, with the output of that command (presumably, an empty string) substituted in place.
- It has a trailing, unmatched backtick at the end, making it invalid syntax.

Comment: Why not `alias Mylistdir="ls -la "$MYDAIR"; `?

Comment: @EdHeal, aliases aren't enabled in noninteractive shells by default (which is why the OP's "no, this is for a script" made sense).

Comment: @EdHeal, ...also, there are very severe limits in what you can do with them; they're only capable of prefix substitution, making them inadequate for anything where you need nontrivial conditional logic, or arguments anywhere other than tail position.